# Force subset of webpages as HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I would like to force a subset of webpages to https and all other webpages as http.
In htaccess I use the following script that I found in another post, but that wasn't working...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login|signup)\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !(login|signup)\.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

HTTP is forced as it should be, HTTPS is forced as it should be, but eg https://mywebsite.com/signup produces an infinite loop error in my browser. Any ideas what goes wrong?

I changed to code to the following which seems to work, but now the SSL is only partially implemented due to secure and insecure items on the webpage. I checked the URLS to e.g. images, style sheets and external javascript files bit these are all relative and shouldn't pose a problem... If someone knows how to deal with this I'd be glad to hear it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/signup$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !signup$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

Comment: No need to force HTTP for non login/signup pages (BTW, what about account pages (if you have any) -- are they will be served via HTTP?). Instead generate proper URLs in your code in first place (i.e. instead of `<a href="/aboutus">` do `<a href="http://www.example.com/aboutus">`) so the customer will always go to HTTP without help from mod_rewrite. If customer wants to go to home page or any other page via HTTPS .. then let him -- there is nothing wrong with that. As long as you will have all links with proper URLs this would never happen unless customer intentionally changes the URL.

Comment: By not forcing HTTP you will not have an issue with insecure content (CSS/JS/Images) on secure pages. This is how I do code my websites all the time. Yes -- it's quite a bit of work to change all the links to include domain name and protocol in existing pages ... but for new pages/new project it makes **no difference** (no additional overhead). Yes -- you should be able to fix it via mod_rewrite (add one or 2 more conditions) .. but that not the right way (at least in my opinion).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I now use mod_rewrite to force https on those pages that require the connection to be secured. I removed the part that forced http, since this also forced references on secured pages to e.g. js/css/image files to be redirected to http (these files didn't validate in the RewriteCond) and gave the problem of having secure and non-secure items on the same page. With referencing everything properly to http or https (and for the latter force https in case the user changes the url) with complete URLS as you suggested everything works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding this line somewhere on top of your .htaccess:

   `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`
2. Maybe you have some other rules that do this redirect -- it would be good if you provide whole contents of your .htaccess file.
3. You may have redirect inside the actual php script.

In any acse -- if you can edit Apache's config files (httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf) then you can **enable rewrite debugging** (`RewriteLoglevel 9`) and see what exactly is going on -- **this is the best option** (if you can).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding -MultiViews doesn't change the error, there are no other redirecting rules, I completely cleaned up my htaccess file for debugging. I don't have access to the config file, but I'll ask my host about it.

Comment: @DigitalMD If it is Shared Hosting then I doubt they will do this for you (very unlikely) as it requires restarting Apache + such log is growing VERY fast .. and I'm unsure if it can be enabled for 1 specific domain only...